# How to use ContourPlot3D for Piecewise 3D function

Tags: plotting

How would I plot in 3D: 
$\begin{cases} (4 - z^2) = x^2 + y^2, 2 \le z \le 4 \\
x^2 + y^2 = 4, -2 \le z \le 2 \end{cases}$.

I tried http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html

`ContourPlot3D[
 Piecewise[{(4 - z)^2 == x ^2 + y^2, 
   2 \le z \le 4}, {x^2 + y^2 = 4, -2 \le z \le 2}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3
  , 3}, {z, -2, 4}]`

I realise there's tex in my code but I don't know how otherwise to symbolise my attempt.

Comment: Your code omits the function `Piecewise` -- how did you try to use it?  Also, your code mixes Mathematica with TeX -- I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: Your first equation has only one point of trueness, so just delete it and do `ContourPlot3D[4 == x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks. I emended my question. `Piecewise` still doesn't function though.

Comment: @Coolwater: Would you please explain "one true point of trueness"?

Comment: I thought your first equation would give an empty contour plot, because only one point in R^3 satisfy it. The thing is I was looking at your latex equations which says (4-z^2) rather than (4-z)^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would plot each separately and combine them:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[(4 - z)^2 == (x^2 + y^2), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 2, 4}],
 ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Piecewise version :

```
ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 == 
                Piecewise[{{(4 - z)^2, 2 <= z <= 4}, {4, -2 <= z <= 2}}],
                 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 4}, PlotRange -> All ]
```