# Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, generative-art

I'd like to create transparent graphs like the following from P1095, *Calculus* 6th Ed, by James Stewart. Can *Mathematica* accomplish this? By "transparent," I mean the ability to see the interior, intersection, boundaries etc. preferrably with dashed hidden lines.

[image]

Would someone please explain how to do this for a function like [\begin{cases} (4 - z^2) = x^2 + y^2, 2 \le z \le 4 \\
x^2 + y^2 = 4, -2 \le z \le 2 \end{cases}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45409/how-to-use-contourplot3d-for-piecewise-3d-function)

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/AddTransparencyToPlots.html doesn't appear to be very helpful in that respect.

Comment: Related: [20945](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/dashed-mesh-behind-3d-object).  Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6353337/915703) on SO.

Comment: Can you describe your specific goal a bit more clearly? Right now it is too fuzzy/broad. Do you want dashed hidden lines?

Comment: @YvesKlett: I've emended my question. Is it better? Yes, I'd want dashed lines for the opposite side that's facing away from me.

Comment: Please add this important bit of info to the question. Any code you already worked on would also be most welcome.

Comment: IMHO that figure could be drawn using Tikz, for example, with LaTeX. It is a draw, not a real graph or surface.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**Update:** This function has been updated to compatible with version 12.x and made available on Wolfram Function Repository as `ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"]`:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Graphics3DSketch

---

Yes we can. The following `DashedGraphics3D[ ]` function is designed to convert ordinary `Graphics3D` object to the "line-drawing" style raster image.

```
Clear[DashedGraphics3D]
DashedGraphics3D::optx = 
        "Invalid options for Graphics3D are omitted: `1`.";
Off[OptionValue::nodef];
Options[DashedGraphics3D] = {ViewAngle -> 0.4, 
            ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 0.5}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
            ImageSize -> 800};
DashedGraphics3D[basegraph_, effectFunction_: Identity, 
            opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; ! 
            MatchQ[Flatten[{effectFunction}], {(Rule | RuleDelayed)[__] ..}] :=

    Module[{basegraphClean = basegraph /. (Lighting -> _):>Sequence[], exceptopts, fullopts, frontlayer, dashedlayer, borderlayer,
            face3DPrimitives = {Cuboid, Cone, Cylinder, Sphere, Tube, 
                    BSplineSurface}
            },

        exceptopts = FilterRules[{opts}, Except[Options[Graphics3D]]];
        If[exceptopts =!= {},
            Message[DashedGraphics3D::optx, exceptopts]
            ];
        fullopts = 
            Join[FilterRules[Options[DashedGraphics3D], Except[#]], #] &@
                FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]];

        frontlayer = Show[
                    basegraphClean /. Line[pts__] :> {Thick, Line[pts]} /.
                        h_[pts___] /; MemberQ[face3DPrimitives, h]
                                :> {EdgeForm[{Thick}], h[pts]},
                    fullopts,
                    Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
                    ] // Rasterize;

        dashedlayer = Show[
                    basegraphClean /.
                            {Polygon[__] :> {}, Line[pts__] :> {Dashed, Line[pts]}} /.
                        h_[pts___] /; MemberQ[face3DPrimitives, h]
                                :> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Dashed}], h[pts]},
                    fullopts
                    ] // Rasterize;

        borderlayer = Show[basegraphClean /. RGBColor[__] :> Black,
                            ViewAngle -> (1 - .001) OptionValue[ViewAngle],
                            Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Black}},
                            fullopts,
                            Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
                            ] // Rasterize // GradientFilter[#, 1] & // ImageAdjust;

        ImageSubtract[frontlayer, dashedlayer] // effectFunction //
                        ImageAdd[frontlayer // ColorNegate, #] & //
                    ImageAdd[#, borderlayer] & //
                ColorNegate // ImageCrop
        ]
```

### Usage:

`DashedGraphics3D[ ]` has three kinds of arguments. The `basegraph` is the `Graphics3D[ ]` you want to convert. The `effectFunction` is an optional argument, which when used will perform the corresponding image effect to the hidden part. The `opts` are options intended for internal `Graphics3D[ ]`, which are mainly used to determine the posture of the final output. When omitted, it takes values as defined by `Options[DashedGraphics3D]`.

### Example:

```
graph1 = Show[{
                SphericalPlot3D[
                    1, {θ, 1/5 1.2 π, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 1.8 π},
                    PlotStyle -> White,
                    PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black],
                SphericalPlot3D[
                    1, {θ, 0, π/5}, {ϕ, π/4, 2.1 π},
                    PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Lighter[Blue, .9], GrayLevel[.9]],
                    PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black],
                Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Lighter[Pink, .8], GrayLevel[.8]], 
                        Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, .8 Cos[π/5]}}, Sin[π/5]]}]
                },
            PlotRange -> 1.2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
            AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False,
            SphericalRegion -> True];

DashedGraphics3D[graph1]
```

[image: hemisphere]

```
DashedGraphics3D[graph1, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Neutral lighting hemisphere]

**Sidenote:** The hidden border of the cylinder's side-wall can not be extracted by the "shadow" method (described below) used in `DashedGraphics3D[ ]`, so `ParametricPlot3D[ ]`-akin functions are needed instead of simply `Cylinder[ ]`.

```
graph2 = ParametricPlot3D[
            {u Cos[v], u Sin[v], Im[(u Exp[I v]^5)^(1/5)]},
            {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2 π},
            PlotPoints -> 20, Mesh -> {2, 5}, MeshStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False,
            BoundaryStyle -> Black, ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Black}];

DashedGraphics3D[graph2]
```

[image: fan]

Add an oil-painting effect:

```
DashedGraphics3D[graph2,
    ImageAdjust[ImageEffect[Blur[#, 3], {"OilPainting", 3}]] &
    ]
```

[image: fan with special image effect]

As for OP's example:

```
graph3 = Show[{
            ContourPlot3D[(4 - z)^2 == x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 2, 4},
                Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 20],
            ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 2},
                Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
            },
        PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-2, 4}}]

DashedGraphics3D[graph3, ViewAngle -> .6, ViewPoint -> {3, 2, 1}]
```

[image: OP's graphics]

### Explanation:

Take `graph1` as example. The `frontlayer` generates a solid style graphic using `{"Ambient", White}` lighting, where every object supposed to be hidden are all invisible:

[image: frontlayer]

The `dashedlayer` does the opposite to the `frontlayer`. It sets all faces transparent, and all edges and lines `Dashed`:

[image: dashedlayer]

Apparently, subtracting `frontlayer` from `dashedlayer`, we can extract the hidden part with dashed-style (on which `effectFunction` is applied.), then we add it back to `frontlayer`:

[image: innerlines]

Now the only missed part is the outline contour. We solve this problem by first using `{"Ambient", Black}` lighting to generate the shadow of the whole graphics, then using `GradientFilter` to extract the outline, which is the `borderlayer`:

[image: borderlayer]

Combine `frontlayer`, `dashedlayer` and `borderlayer` properly, we get our final result.

Comment: Just... WOW! (Oh, and +1)

Comment: @Peltio Thanks :) Too bad it's too slow to be wrapped in a `Dynamic`...

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious!

Comment: @YvesKlett Hmm, I actually looked up my dictionary and I can't believe this word do exist! I think it's much harder than Chinese! And Thank you! :)

Comment: Wow.. I have to agree with @YvesKlett. [Here is Oxford dictionary definition of supercalifragilisticexpialidocious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious).

Comment: Pronouncing is much simpler than reading here - once you've watched Mary Poppins you will be all right.  Thank *you* for another excellent answer,  this will come in very handy :D

Comment: @Murta YvesKlett Thanks, it does be `Simplify`-ed when I heard the pronunciation :D Regarding to my function, I still can't think of an easy way (so differential geometry can be avoided) to hint the outlines like the hidden side-wall of the cylinder.

Comment: @LePressentiment Hope you like it -- though not perfect :)

Comment: Impressive, but apparently does not work with 3D `GraphicsComplex`, at least not under 12.3.1, see
`Graphics3DSketch@Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[{{0,0,0},{2,0,0},{2,20},{0,2,0},{1,1,2}},Polygon[{{1,2,5},{2,3,5},{3,4,5},{4,1,5}}]]]`

Comment: @MartinRommel That was by design. Because my original idea was to target "surfaces" generated by all sorts of `*Plot3D` functions, and those "surfaces" are internally hundreds of polygons (triangles). Showing all the internal borders of those polygons is undesired. In your case, we can modify how `dashedlayer` is generated to bring back the wanted edges. Say, instead of `Polygon[__] :> {}`, we could use `p : Polygon[__] :> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Dashed], p}`.

Answer (score 30):

Seeing Silvia's phenomenal answer I've been inspired to take a crack at this. My method requires the use of `ColorFunction` so it only works for plots rather than general `Graphics3D` geometry. However, it does find silhouette edges in the interior of the image, as well as those hidden behind other surfaces (such as the missing side walls of the internal cylinder in Silvia's answer). Unfortunately I don't know how to make the hidden lines dashed; I've just made them a different colour.

There are [lots of ways to render 3D shapes in line art style](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~decarlo/readings/gooch-sg03c.pdf). One of the simplest is to [take a depth map and just run edge detection on it](http://otherthings.com/uw/loose/sketch.html). In Mathematica I don't think we have access to the depth map of the plot, but we can get a similar effect by having pixel colours correspond directly to position:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, z]]]
```

[image]

Like Silvia's `borderLayer`, we'll use edge detection to find silhouette edges. However, we'll need to oversample the plot to avoid ugly pixelation and aliasing artifacts.

```
oversample = 3;
thickness = 2;
edges = Dilation[
  EdgeDetect[Image[plot, ImageSize -> 360 oversample], 1, 0.05], 
  DiskMatrix[Round[(oversample*thickness - 1)/2]]]
```

[image]

Okay, now what about hidden silhouette edges? Simple: we'll make them not hidden any more by turning the opacity down!

```
plot2 = Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  MaxRecursion -> 5, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, z]], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]
```

[image]

```
edges2 = Dilation[
  EdgeDetect[Image[plot2, ImageSize -> 360 oversample], 1, 0.05], 
  DiskMatrix[Round[(oversample*thickness - 1)/2]]]
```

[image]

And lo, we shall combine them:

```
image = SetAlphaChannel[
   Image[ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0}, Reverse@ImageDimensions[edges]]], 
   edges];
image2 = SetAlphaChannel[
   Image[ConstantArray[{0.8, 0.6, 1}, 
     Reverse@ImageDimensions[edges2]]], edges2];
(*If anyone knows of an easier way to create a constant-colour image \
of the same dimensions as a given image,please let me know.*)
ImageResize[ImageCompose[image2, image], Scaled[1/oversample]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great idea for self-made depth map! Maybe we can join the extracted points with `Line` and introduce the `Dashed`.

Comment: @Silvia: Thanks! I had a similar idea and tried using `FindCurvePoints`, but it failed to join up the contours completely. To see this, set `oversample = 1` and `thickness = 1` and try `ListCurvePathPlot[Position[ImageData[edges], 1]]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tested a lot, but I think the classical [`GrayLevel` z-buffer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FrFa0.png) will give a better edge. Maybe we can even slice the `Graphics3D` alone the line of sight. (But that might be too inefficient..)

Comment: Now have a look at [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cDXlw.png) ;) (I'm still studying the new possibilities, haven't got enough things for an update.)

Comment: @Silvia: Sweet! How did you do it?

Comment: Basically I derived the equation of the edges and used the `MeshFunctions`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from [here](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/6304338553).

```
F[x_] := Animate[
  With[{v = RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}][5 {1, 1, 1}]}, 
   Binarize@
     Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[], x}, 
      Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> v, 
      SphericalRegion -> True] + (Binarize[
       Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], x}, Boxed -> False, 
        ViewPoint -> v, SphericalRegion -> True, 
        Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]] - 
      Binarize[
       Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black, Dashing[{0.02, 0.05}]}], 
         FaceForm[], x}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> v, 
        SphericalRegion -> True]])], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  AnimationRunning -> False]
F[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]]
```