# Arbitrary hollow cylinders in mathematica 9

Tags: plotting, version-9, geometry

I'm having trouble displaying a hollow cylinder in Mathematica 9. A hollow cylinder looks like this:

[image: hollow cylinder]

I tried to use `RevolutionPlot3D` with a step function. It displays as what I want, but a collection of them in a `Show[]` is really buggy.

To prevent an X-Y problem, I'll say why I need this shape. I'm making a diagram to show how the integral of a volume of revolution can be approximated by a collection of hollow cylinders, like how the integral of a 1D function can be approximated by a collection of rectangles covering the undergraph.

I want my diagram to look something like this terrible drawing:

[image]

A `Plot3D` bounds the cylinders from above. The whole assembly is shown in a cross section, with one or two cylinders protruding out of the cross section to show what they are supposed to be.

If there is a better way to do this I'm open to that, but if there's some hidden CSG functions in Mathematica that would do the job I would be forever grateful to hear about them

Comment: Check out [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/sketch-type-graphics-with-transparency-and-dashed-hidden-lines/45435#45435)

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARKHd.png) can be done with `Show[{RegionPlot3D[   2.4 < x^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Mesh -> None], RegionPlot3D[0.5 < x^2 + y^2 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, Mesh -> None]}]` pretty easily :)

Comment: @Öskå make an answer out of it? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nexo9.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myData = {{2, 1, #}, {1, 1, 0}} & /@ Table[1/(n + 2) + .2 RandomReal[], {n, 1, 15}];

SectorChart3D[myData, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @blacklemon67 Great... glad to help.  If you play around with the `ColorFunction`, you can likely highlight just one ring (red, say), as in your hand sketch.