# Volumes of Revolution with detailed diagram

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

All, In calculus I have to do images such as the following in helping explain technique to students. This one is by rotating $y=\sqrt x$ about the x-axis, an image copied from Stewart's Calculus textbook.

[image]

I am wondering if anyone has experience in doing this and has any links to share, some sample files, etc., which would give me an idea on how to best make the image on the right.

Thanks.

**Close to what I need:**

Consider:

```
Show[Plot[{-Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 1.25}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
  PlotStyle -> Black,
  Filling -> True, FillingStyle -> Directive[LightBlue],
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Arrowheads[0.03]],
  Ticks -> {{1}, {-1, 1}},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ],
 Graphics[{
   GrayLevel[0.7], EdgeForm[Black],
   Disk[{1, 0}, {.1, 1}],
   Pink,
   Rectangle[{0.47, -Sqrt[0.5]}, {0.53, Sqrt[0.5]}],
   Disk[{0.47, 0}, {.07, Sqrt[0.5]}],
   Disk[{0.53, 0}, {.07, Sqrt[0.5]}],
   Text[Style["\[CapitalDelta]x", Black], {0.5, -Sqrt[0.5]}, {0, 2}]
   }]
 ]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

If I can come up with a way of joining (taking the union of) the first rectangle and first circle, so that the edge form only marks the exterior of the joined form, then I might have a solution. Any suggestions on how I might do that?

**Final Update:**

Thanks to @kguler's amazing answer, I learned an exceptional amount of material and possibilities. I made a few adjustments to his code. Here is my final example.

```
curve = Line@
   Table[{.53, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/2, 
     3 Pi/2, Pi/20}];

poly = Polygon[
   Join[
    Table[{.53, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/2, 
      Pi/2, Pi/20}], 
    Table[{.47, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/2, 
      3 Pi/2, Pi/20}]
    ]
   ];

g1 = Plot[{-Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 1.25}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   Filling -> True, FillingStyle -> Directive[LightBlue], 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Arrowheads[0.03]], 
   Ticks -> {{1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];

g2 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.7], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{1, 0}, {.1, 1}],
     Pink, EdgeForm[Black], poly, Black, curve, 
    Text[Style["\[CapitalDelta]x", Black], {0.5, -Sqrt[0.5]}, {0, 
      2}]}];

Show[g1, g2, Graphics[{
   Blue, Line[{{0.5, 0}, {0.5, Sqrt[0.5]}}],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\)", Black, Bold], {0.5, 
     Sqrt[0.5]/2}, {-1.5, 0}],
   PointSize[Medium], Point[{0.5, 0}],
   Text[Style["x", Black, Bold], {0.5, 0}, {0, 1.5}]
   }]
 ]
```

And the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45435/17).

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for their answers. However, not quite what I am looking for. I have edited by original post with an attempt of what I'd like to use, but it sill is not quite adequate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

> *a way of joining (taking the union of) the first rectangle and first circle, so that the edge form only marks the exterior of the joined form*

```
p = 100; 
curve = Line@ Table[{.53, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Sin[-2 Pi k /p], 
   Cos[-2 Pi k /p]}, {k, -1 + p/2}];
poly = Polygon[Join[t1 = Table[{.47, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Sin[-2 Pi k /p], 
        Cos[-2 Pi k /p]}, {k, -1 + p/2}], 
   Reverse@Table[{.53, 0} + {.07, Sqrt[0.5]} {Sin[2 Pi k /p], Cos[2 Pi k /p]}, 
   {k, -1 + p/2}], {t1[[1]]}]]; 

g1 = Plot[{-Sqrt[x], Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 1.25}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  Filling -> True, FillingStyle -> Directive[LightBlue], 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Arrowheads[0.03]], 
  Ticks -> {{1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];

g2 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.7], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Disk[{1, 0}, {.1, 1}], Pink, EdgeForm[Black], poly, Black, curve, 
  Text[Style["\[CapitalDelta]x", Black], {0.5, -Sqrt[0.5]}, {0, 2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Original post:**

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, Sqrt[x]}, {.5, Min[Sqrt[.55], Sqrt[x]]}, 
   {.6, Min[Sqrt[.55], Sqrt[x]]}, {1., Sqrt[x]}, 
   {ConditionalExpression[x, .5 <= x <= .6], Sqrt[.55]}}, 
 {x, 0, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5, Blue], Opacity[.9, Red], Opacity[.9, Red], 
   Opacity[.7, Cyan], Opacity[1, Red]}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> {True, False, True},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice, exactly what might work in general. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @David, my pleasure. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer. I've made a few adjustments and added it to my original post.

Answer (score 11):

Just purely for fun: to illustrate approximation of volume integral.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{dp, dpl, dpu, r = Range[0, 1, 1/n], f, cc, lb, la, ub, ua, 
   ll, ul},
  dp = Range[0, 1, 1/#] & /@ Range[2, 100];
  dpl = Total[Pi Most[#]/(Length@# - 1)] & /@ dp;
  dpu = Total[Pi Rest[#]/(Length@# - 1)] & /@ dp;
  f = Sqrt /@ r;
  cc = Partition[{#, 0, 0} & /@ r, 2, 1];
  {lb, la} = 
   Transpose@MapThread[{Cylinder[#1, #2], Pi #2^2/n} &, {cc, Most@f}];
  {ub, ua} = 
   Transpose@MapThread[{Cylinder[#1, #2], Pi #2^2/n} &, {cc, Rest@f}];
  ll = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], lb}];
  ul = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], ub}];
  Row[{
    Show[If[c == 1, ll, Graphics3D[]], If[d == 1, ul, Graphics3D[]], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{u, Cos[v] Sqrt[u], Sin[v] Sqrt[u]}, {u, 0, 
       1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> False], 
     ImageSize -> 300],
    Grid[{{"Area", N[Pi/2]}, {"Lower bound", 
       N[Total@la]}, {"Upper bound", N[Total@ua]}}], 
    ListPlot[{dpl, dpu}, GridLines -> {{n}, {Pi/2}}, 
     ImageSize -> 300]}]]
 , {{c, 0, "lower limit"}, {0, 1}}, {{d, 0, "upper limit"}, {0, 
   1}}, {n, Range[2, 100, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also a nice answer.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thank you...it was just fun to illustrate the limiting procedure...and I thought fit in with educational  spirit of question :)

Comment: @ubpdqn: I will definitely be examining this closely before the fall term starts. Very nice application. I just needed something different for what I was working on at the moment. I appreciate your help.