# Plotting the outline of a 3D shape

Tags: plotting

Is there anyway to make a 3D plot that's only the outline or silhouette of the plot, without all the lighting, shadow, etc? For example, if I were to plot a hyperboloid, I would want something like this

[image: mad paint skills]

It seemed that `Glow` almost does that—it removes all "3D effects" like lightning but it doesn't create the outline so I just get a flat shape. That is, a hyperboloid with `Glow[White]` on white background is invisible without the mesh (which I don't want to add).

Comment: Related or duplicate: [45410](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/57).