# 3D plotting: make some edges of the bounding box dashed

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to produce a very simple 3D scatterplot with

```
ListPointPlot3D[stratdatacleannew]
```

with `stratdatacleannew` a list of 3-tuples. However, for ease of viewing, I would like to have a bounding box that has dashed lines instead of solid lines for edges that would be hidden from the viewer. How can I do this?

Comment: closely related/possible duplicate: [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/125)