# How to draw sketches of objects using lines (curves) only

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Update

Thanks for your comments, now I see that it's not easy to have 3D graphics  in vector form. This is fine though, because the major reason that I'd like to do it in mathematica is that I'd like to create a piece of code, which can reads the DH parameters of the manipulator then generate the robots automatically,  potentially similar to a demonstration file I recently encountered, [an deomnstration file](http://to-understand-the-relative-position-and-orientation-of-adjacent-joints-of-th).

If this is possible, then I don't have to modify the dimensions of the parts individually in Solidworks. So if I don't require vector format, is it possibe? Notice that the approach suggested by Silvia seems a bit difficult to use, like I can't drag it, etc.

If there is not a more simpler approach, I will consider using other forms, like in the demonstration. Thanks.

Original Post

I'd like to draw an illustrative graph similar to the attached figure. To do this, I need to first create the objects, then display them in edges. I tested this on cylinder, but I can only mangage to show the edges of two circles, but can't get it in a similar form as in the first figure. I wonder if it is possible to show several objects in such a fashion? [image: desired figure]
[image: a trial of edge sketch].

Alternatively, is there any other suggested way to do such a sketch? Previously, I usually use Solidworks to generate such a model, but I'm thinking whether it is possible to do it in mathematica in vector format so that it might be easier to manipulate. Thanks.

Comment: tried [this answer by Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45435/125)?

Comment: You don't get faces because you told Graphics3D not to draw them: "`FaceForm[]` draws no faces" is the very first bullet point in the FaceForm documentation. More in general, this would require enormous effort and I don't think  you could effectively export a 3D graphic as a vector format anyway.

Comment: This is difficult, unfortunately ... I think currently the only reasonable option is an image-processing solution like the one by Silvia. This type of solution will never be perfect, unfortunately.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, this looks like a good idea, but it's a bit inconvient because it seems that we can no longer drag to modify the orientation etc., we can only modify the orientation in a limited choice. But I do agree that this is a good approach in many circumstances.