# Make 3D graphics "look" 2D

Tags: graphics3d

I'm working with some basic 3D graphics stuff:

```
g1 =
  CoordinateBoundsArray[
   {
    {0, 1},
    {0, 1}
    },
   {.1, .1}
   ];
g2 = Map[# + {.05, .05} &, g1, {2}];
fullG = Join[Flatten[g1, 1], Flatten[g2, 1]];

substrate =
  {
   EdgeForm[None],
   GrayLevel[.8], 
   Cuboid[{ -.05, -.05, -.1}, {1.1, 1.1, .01}]
   };

$viewOptions =
  {
   Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotRange -> Transpose@{{ -.05, -.05, -.1}, {1.1, 1.1, .5}},
   ViewVector -> 2.5*{1, .6, .3},
   ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
   };

firstCylinders = Cylinder[{Append[#, 0], Append[#, .1]}, .03] & /@ fullG;
bigCylinderGraphics =
 Graphics3D[
  {
   substrate,
   {
    EdgeForm[Hue[.15, 1, .9]],
    Hue[.15, 1, 1], 
    firstCylinders
    }
   },
  $viewOptions
  ]
```

[image]

And I find myself wishing it looked more like what one would do with, e.g. [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/) where it's composed of 2D primitives.

If the new toon-shading stuff were available in 12.0 I think that'd probably be good enough, but absent that I'm wondering if there's any good way to make the cylindrical components *less* well shaded and more "flat", e.g. like this (but perspective-correct and all that):

[image]

Here's an initial attempt with `Inset` that seems like it will not be able to work (but I'd love to be proved wrong):

```
cylinder2D =
  Graphics[
   {
    White,
    {
     EdgeForm@Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black],
     Disk[{.5, .26}, {.5, .25}, {\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
     },
    {
     EdgeForm@Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], White],
     Rectangle[
      {0, .25},
      {1, 1.5}
      ],
     Black,
     AbsoluteThickness[2],
     Line[{{0, .25}, {0, 1.5}}],
     Line[{{1, .25}, {1, 1.5}}]
     },
    {
     EdgeForm@Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black],
     Disk[{.5, 1.5}, {.5, .25}]
     }
    }
   ];

Graphics3D[
 {
  substrate,
  Map[
   Inset[
     cylinder2D /. White -> Orange,
     Append[#, .03],
     {Center, Bottom},
     {20, 20}
     ] &,
   fullG
   ]
  },
 ImageSize -> 500,
 $viewOptions
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: For the shading problem you could just use `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}` but you will miss solid edges 'around' projections. So you could try to adapt: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/5478 for this purpose.