# Help with a simple figure for a poster

Tags: plotting, graphics, image, image3d

I am asking for someone's kind help with creating the figure blow for a poster. The figure I have is a bit too basic and I am don't know how to use Photoshop as yet.

[image]Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is possible in Mathematica. [Here's some code](https://pastebin.com/34zh70Ci) But seriously, do it in Photoshop, Gimp, Affinity Photo, inkscape or whatever. It will all make this a lot easier and look better in the end.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/sketch-type-graphics-with-transparency-and-dashed-hidden-lines

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
cyl[x_] = {
   Circle[{x + -2, 0}, {0.2, 1}],
   Circle[{x + 2, 0}, {0.2, 1}],
   Line[{{x + -2, 1}, {x + 2, 1}}],
   Line[{{x + -2, -1}, {x + 2, -1}}],
   Arrow[{{x + -2, 0}, {x + -1.92, -0.5}}],
   Arrow[{{x + -2, 0}, {x + -2, 0.7}}],
   
   Dashing[0.005],
   Circle[{x + -2, 0}, {0.1, 0.7}],
   Circle[{x + 2, 0}, {0.1, 0.7}],
   Line[{{x + -2, 0.7}, {x + 2, 0.7}}],
   Line[{{x + -2, -0.7}, {x + 2, -0.7}}]
   };
Graphics[{PointSize[0.008], Arrowheads[0.02], Thickness[0.001],
  cyl[-3],
  cyl[3],
  Arrow[{{-0.7, 0}, {0.7, 0}}],
  Point[{{-5, 0.85}, {5, 0.85}, {-3, 0.7}, {-3, -1}, {3, 
     1}, {3, -0.7}, {-1, 0.85}, {1, 0.85}}],
  Text @@@ {{"Rin", {-4.7, 
      0.3}}, {"Rout", {-4.6, -0.3}}, {"rin", {1.3, 
      0.3}}, {"rout", {1.3, -0.3}}, {"P", {-5.2, 0.85}}, {"p", {0.8, 
      0.85}}, {"Q", {-0.8, 0.85}}, {"q", {5.2, 0.85}}, {"R", {-3, 
      0.85}}, {"S", {-3, -0.85}}, {"r", {3, 0.85}}, {"s", {3, -0.85}}},
  ImageSize -> 400
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also import an image of this:

```
cylinders = Graphics3D[
 {
  {Opacity[0.5], White, 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}, 0.5]},
  {Opacity[0.2], Blue, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}, 1]
   
   
   }
  },
 Boxed -> False,ViewPoint -> {-12, -10, 20}]
```

export:

```
Export["image.png",Image[cylinders]]
```

And then annotate the image in Inkscape, etc.